# knowledge graphs with tuples

Tags: python, graph, networkx, knowledge-graph

My goal is to create a knowledge graph using a csv file which includes, source, edge and target. What I have tried so far:

- it is not visible in the image, but I have two edges: 1) used for 2) related to.
- I have target tuples with 20 words.

first image is what I would like to see as a format. second image is the head of my csv data file, the third image shows the failed graph visualization as a result of this code.

```
# create a directed-graph from a dataframe
import networkx as nx

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tuple_predictions_IB_for_graph, "source", "target", 
                          edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues, pos = pos)
plt.show()
```

[image: source]

[image: desired format of the outputted graph]

[image: actual resulting graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `explode` method of your dataframe to make an entry for each target in your rows so that each target aligns with its appropriate source, then you'll get the nodes as desired.

```
# Make sample data
tuple_predictions_IB_for_graph = pd.DataFrame({'source':['motherboard','screen','keyboard','bluetooth','webcam'],
                                               'edge':['related to']*4+['other_label'],
                                               'target':[['computer','keyboard','mouse','monitor'],
                                                         ['monitor','mouse','computer','tv'],
                                                         ['mouse','keyboard','monitor'],
                                                         ['toothe enamel','tooth decay','tooth fairy'],
                                                         ['webcam','camera','video camera','eyepiece']]})

# Explode the target column
tuple_df_exploded = tuple_predictions_IB_for_graph.explode(column = 'target')
tuple_df_exploded.head()
#         source        edge    target
# 0  motherboard  related to  computer
# 0  motherboard  related to  keyboard
# 0  motherboard  related to     mouse
# 0  motherboard  related to   monitor
# 1       screen  related to   monitor

# Make the graph accepting the 'edge' column as an edge attribute
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tuple_df_exploded,
                            source='source',target='target',edge_attr='edge',
                            create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())

pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx(g,pos)
# draw the edges to make them a specific color based on the 'edge' attribute from the df
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos,edgelist=g.edges(),
                       edge_color=[{'related to':'black',
                                    'other_label':'red'}[edge_label]
                                   for u,v,edge_label in g.edges(data='edge')]);
```

[image: graph with colored edges]

Comment: brilliant! I went ahead and accepted your answer. Quick follow up: My graph looks circular, do you know what is the difference between the nx.draw_networkx vs nx.draw?

Comment: `nx.draw` internally calls `nx.draw_networkx` (As stated in the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw)) and only performs some operations for the axis, e.g., disabling them, background color white, full details in the [code](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw)